# Using several renderers with Three.js?

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, three.js, rendering

I would like to use two WebGL renderers (using Three.js) in the browser. I have done this using two 'div' elements each attached to two different renderer objects:

```
   <div id="ThreeJS1"...>
   <div id="ThreeJS1"...>
   ...
   renderer1 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
   renderer2 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
   ...
   container1 = document.getElementById( 'ThreeJS1' );
   container1.appendChild( renderer1.domElement );

   container2 = document.getElementById( 'ThreeJS2' );
   container2.appendChild( renderer2.domElement );
   ...
```

I get two renderer displays as expected but the problem is that the object in each 'div' are not rendered properly as they are black regardless of trying to change their colour or using wireframe.

I assumed that splitting the screen and using several renderers would work using the method for a single renderer. What am I doing wrong? I appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Solution: I was using MeshLambertMaterial with no lights. I'm embarassed.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the name of the second div. If put:

div id="ThreeJS1"...
div id="ThreeJS2"...
...

It does not work the code?